# Complex algebraic system of equations problem solving

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, word-problem

A strange announcement was made on the radio about a local election with three candidates: Mrs Allan, Mr Baxter and Ms Campbell.
“Mrs Allan beat Mr Baxter by one eighth of the total votes cast.
Mr Baxter beat Ms Campbell by a seventh of the total votes cast.
The votes cast for Mrs Allan was 350 fewer than 3 times Ms Campbell's votes.”
How many votes did each candidate get?

My answer was:
Mrs Allen = 1300 votes
Mr Baxter = 950 votes
Ms Campbell = 550 votes

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can make some equations, for mrs Allen beating Baxter: $$ a=b+(a+b+c)/8$$Baxter beats Campbell:$$ b=c+(a+b+c)/7$$and Allen and Campbell $$a+350= 3c$$ So yes you are correct.